# How to find power absorbed or delivered by current source?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, homework

How do I solve this:

> Find the power absorbed/delivered by the 6 A current source in the circuit shown here:
>
> [image: schematic]

Comment: Find the voltage at the T and do the math.

Comment: Use Kirchoff and Ohm's laws

Comment: Could you please show how?

Comment: What is the current through the 10R? What does that make the voltage across the 10R? What does that make the voltage at the top of the 6A. and hence across 6A?

Comment: Sorry still dont get it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework assignment and OP has shown zero effort.

Comment: @KravinovSergei can you show any working that you have done so far? How you attempted to solve it yourself so we can see where you went wrong and point out the mistakes made so we can help you learn

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Kirchoffs Current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) first of all.

The law states that the sum of current flowing *into* a node is equal to the current flowing *out* of the node. The diagram shows the direction of the current flow. Use this to figure out the current across the 10 ohm resistor.

Once you have that, you can use [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) to find the voltage *drop* across the resistor. Then you should be able to find the voltage at the node. You can then find the voltage across the current sources and use [power equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) to solve it.

I haven't answered it completely for you, but this should provide all the guidelines and everything you need to solve your problem

Comment: He can also make the central node GND (0V) and everything will be easier to compute, if a ground is not already specified.

Comment: Any reason why this was given a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Sum the currents at the central node: the current in the resistor is 3A (orientation: left to right). Then the potential with respect to ground will be 10V + 3* 10 Ohm = 40 V. Therefore, the voltage across the current source (actually both, they are in parallel) will be 40 V- 6 V = 34 V. The power delivered is 34 V * 6 A = 204 W.

Comment: had to down vote for doing the guys homework for him.. sorry.

Comment: no problem man. Some people understand only by examples. If they are smart enough, then they can understand. If they are dumb, they will just copy the answer.

Comment: how do you know its delivered?

Comment: its not a hw question its something i cant understand

Comment: @KravinovSergei start here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws then here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law

Comment: Apologies, I too had to downvote for doing all the work for him. If you revise the answer then I am happy to change my vote. See my answer above where I went through the steps needed, without giving away the answer. This should help the OP to learn, which is what we want to do here

Comment: No problem, I can live with this. I won't edit my post just to remove any downvotes. You already gave the answer in the form you want.